# Calculating concurrency from a set of ranges

Tags: sql, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I have a set of rows containing a start timestamp and a duration. I want to perform various summaries using the overlap or concurrency.

For example: peak daily concurrency, peak concurrency grouped on another column.

Example data:

```
timestamp,duration
2016-01-01 12:00:00,300
2016-01-01 12:01:00,300
2016-01-01 12:06:00,300
```

I would like to know that peak for the period was 12:01:00-12:05:00 at 2 concurrent.

Any ideas on how to achieve this using BigQuery or, less exciting, a Map/Reduce job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a per-minute resolution, with session lengths of up to 255 minutes:

```
SELECT session_minute, COUNT(*) c
FROM (
  SELECT start, DATE_ADD(start, i, 'MINUTE') session_minute FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT TIMESTAMP("2015-04-30 10:14") start, 7 minutes
    ),(
      SELECT TIMESTAMP("2015-04-30 10:15") start, 12 minutes
    ),(
      SELECT TIMESTAMP("2015-04-30 10:15") start, 12 minutes
    ),(
      SELECT TIMESTAMP("2015-04-30 10:18") start, 12 minutes
    ),(
      SELECT TIMESTAMP("2015-04-30 10:23") start, 3 minutes
    ) 
  ) a
  CROSS JOIN [fh-bigquery:public_dump.numbers_255] b
  WHERE a.minutes>b.i
)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> STEP 1 - First you need find all periods (start and end) with
>   respective concurrent entries

```
SELECT ts AS start, LEAD(ts) OVER(ORDER BY ts) AS finish, 
       SUM(entry) OVER(ORDER BY ts) AS concurrent_entries
FROM (
  SELECT ts, SUM(entry)AS entry 
  FROM 
    (SELECT ts, 1 AS entry FROM yourTable),
    (SELECT DATE_ADD(ts, duration, 'second') AS ts, -1 AS entry FROM yourTable)
  GROUP BY ts
  HAVING entry != 0
)
ORDER BY ts
```

Assuming input as below

```
(SELECT TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01 12:00:00') AS ts, 300 AS duration),
(SELECT TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01 12:01:00') AS ts, 300 AS duration),
(SELECT TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01 12:06:00') AS ts, 300 AS duration),
(SELECT TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01 12:07:00') AS ts, 300 AS duration),
(SELECT TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01 12:10:00') AS ts, 300 AS duration),
(SELECT TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01 12:11:00') AS ts, 300 AS duration)
```

the output of above query will look somehow like this:

```
start                       finish                      concurrent_entries   
2016-01-01 12:00:00 UTC     2016-01-01 12:01:00 UTC     1    
2016-01-01 12:01:00 UTC     2016-01-01 12:05:00 UTC     2    
2016-01-01 12:05:00 UTC     2016-01-01 12:07:00 UTC     1    
2016-01-01 12:07:00 UTC     2016-01-01 12:10:00 UTC     2    
2016-01-01 12:10:00 UTC     2016-01-01 12:12:00 UTC     3    
2016-01-01 12:12:00 UTC     2016-01-01 12:15:00 UTC     2    
2016-01-01 12:15:00 UTC     2016-01-01 12:16:00 UTC     1    
2016-01-01 12:16:00 UTC     null                        0
```

You might still want to polish above query a little  - but mainly it does what you need

> STEP 2 - now you can do any stats off of above result

For example peak on whole period:

```
SELECT 
  start, finish, concurrent_entries, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY concurrent_entries DESC) AS peak
FROM (
  SELECT ts AS start, LEAD(ts) OVER(ORDER BY ts) AS finish, 
         SUM(entry) OVER(ORDER BY ts) AS concurrent_entries
  FROM (
    SELECT ts, SUM(entry)AS entry FROM 
      (SELECT ts, 1 AS entry FROM yourTable),
      (SELECT DATE_ADD(ts, duration, 'second') AS ts, -1 AS entry FROM yourTable)
    GROUP BY ts
    HAVING entry != 0
  )
)
ORDER BY peak
```